# Tensorflow get all gradient_and_variable pairs in scopes

Tags: tensorflow

I am implementing a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.4773) and the requirement is abstracted as follows. I have a CNN which has multiple layers, each of which is scoped. As the paper needs two example, I have used `opt.compute_gradients(loss)` and `tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()` to obtain `[grad_and_vars1, grad_and_vars2]` (where `grad_and_vars` means gradient and variable pairs and the 1 represents first example).

How could I get the gradient and variable pairs which the corresponding variables are among the required scopes?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a list of variables to [compute_gradients](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/MomentumOptimizer#compute_gradients) via the keyword argument `var_list`. You may also have a look at [tf.trainable_variables()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/trainable_variables) and [tf.contrib.framework.filter_variables()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/framework/filter_variables).

Here's an example to compute the gradients for two different scopes:

```py
all_variables = tf.trainable_variables()
scope1_variables = tf.contrib.framework.filter_variables(all_variables, include_patterns=['name_of_scope1'])
scope2_variables = tf.contrib.framework.filter_variables(all_variables, include_patterns=['name_of_scope2'])
opt = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(lr, momentum)
grad_and_vars1 = opt.compute_gradients(loss, var_list=scope1_variables)
grad_and_vars2 = opt.compute_gradients(loss, var_list=scope2_variables)
```

Comment: Will the order of variables in `scope1_variables` and `scope2_variables` be the same? @chrert

Comment: What do you mean by "the same order"? Since we are talking about variables from different scopes, `scope1_variables` and `scope2_variables` will be disjoint. @Tengerye

Answer (score 0):

I have to supplement the answer from @chrert.

The challenge of the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.4773.pdf) is that it has two loss functions (`l1` and `l2`) and you have to update SOME variables with the gradients related with both functions.

Before using `opt.apply_gradients`, you have to find pairs `(grad1, var1)` computed by `l1` and pairs `(grad2, var2)` computed by `l2`, and combine them where `var1.name==var2.name`.

A simple solution I found is that the pairs computed by `opt.compute_gradients` are of the same order.